# Obtaining OSM Data within Bounds

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am able to download osm data with the following url request 
"http://www.overpass-api.de/api/map?*bbox=7.505549,6.482084,7.511999,6.488254". It is generating a map.osm file, in that some of the roads are extending beyond the bbox limit and not exactly clipped to the bbox.

How do I sort this issue?

Comment: Do you want the way (road) to be included or not included, or do you somehow expect it to be truncated?

Comment: The XAPI compability layer does not clip ways. It selects the whole ways as they have been stored into OSM database http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/XAPI_Compatibility_Layer. With the native Overpass query language you can probably do what you want http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide

Comment: Yes Brad. I want the roads to be truncated at bbox

Comment: Then you have to perform some post-processing. This API will only serve raw data without performing any modifications. If the way starts inside the bounding box but ends outside of it, then you will receive it exactly like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in one of the comments above, you get a filtered subset of the "source data" when you use the OverPass API. It isn't going to modify that source data, which is what truncation implies.

I think the best way forward would be to extract the area you wanted, and import it into a tool like QGIS, and use that to truncate the lines (in QGIS, Vector->Geoprocessing Tools -> Clip). Another alternative would be to render the result you want, then use a raster clip, but the intermediate steps may involve working with data you didn't want.